# Angular - VM Clarity datagrid onscroll event

Tags: angular, typescript, vmware-clarity

If I set max height for Clarity datagrid in Angular (2+), can I handle the onscroll event of the datagrid? 
I want to call a method to do something when user scrolls to the bottom of the datagrid (in case I set max height for the datagrid).

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? If it’s for infinite scrolling/load more rows we recommend using pagination instead.

Comment: Thanks @hippeelee. Is it not recommended to implement infinite scrolling with Clarity Datagrid?

Comment: Pagination is the recommendation here. We haven’t found a way to make infinite scrolling accessible and the UX of infinite scrolling in a datagrid is problematic for users.